# Euler-Lagrange Equation Problem with Holonomic constraint

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle, variational-calculus, constrained-dynamics

I am trying to solve this problem;

> minimizing the functional $\int\sqrt{y^2+y\prime^2+z\prime^2}dx$ with the constraint $y+z=1$ (Here $y\prime=dy/dx$, $z\prime=dz/dx$, and $x$ is the only independent variable).

I tried using Lagrangian Multipliers to minimize the function $$f(y, z, y\prime, z\prime; x)=\sqrt{y^2+y\prime^2+z\prime^2}+\lambda (y+z-1)$$ to get the equations

$
\frac{y}{\sqrt{y^2+y\prime^2+z\prime^2}}+\lambda-\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{y\prime}{\sqrt{y^2+y\prime^2+z\prime^2}})=0
$

$
\lambda-\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{z\prime}{\sqrt{y^2+y\prime^2+z\prime^2}})=0
$

and used $y\prime+z\prime=0$ to simplify the equations. However, this led to a different result when I used $y\prime+z\prime=0$ directly and tried minimizing the function $\sqrt{y^2+2y\prime^2}$ instead. I am new to the concept of holonomic constraints and Lagrange multipliers so I am not sure what I did wrong.